# how many bytes is this struct? - how many bytes is pointer to a struct?

Tags: c

```
struct hello {
   size_t num;
   struct jump *next;
}
```

I get that size_t is 4bytes but how many bytes is struct jump *next?

Comment: `size_t` is not 4 bytes. `sizeof(size_t)` is platform-dependent. As is the size of the struct.

Comment: On 32-bit machine sizeof pointer is 32 bits 4 bytes
On 64 bit machine it's 8 byte. Regardless of what data type they are pointing to, they have fixed size.

Comment: If the question is "How big is type X?", the best and easiest way to find out is with the `sizeof` operator, either on a type name or a variable of that type.  If, on the other hand, the question is "Why is the size of type X equal to Y (I thought it would be Z)?", that's a question you might want to ask here.  (But the answer is usually, "padding".)

Comment: @SteveSummit - not worth the battle. As written the question asks what is the `sizeof (a_pointer);` Unless you take the question from the first part of the Title *"how many bytes is this struct?"* So, the only thing to do is "Objection form -- compound -- multifarious."

Comment: Your claims reflect typical implementation choices, @Ôrel, but C does not require *any* of them to be true.  There are counterexamples, or at least there have been.  Pointers are not necessarily the same size as machine words, they are not necessarily all the same size as each other, and they do not necessarily all have the same representation as each other.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `sizeof` operator:

```
printf("%zu", sizeof(struct jump*));
```